# VB.NET example code for calling other exe to act like as MDI child form? is it possible?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms, mdi

ok here is the scenario.
1. i've create a project that has 1 form named form1.exe
2. i've also create a project that has 1 MDI form.
in this MDI Form. i'would like to call "form1.exe" act like / behave like MDI Form child.
i've tried using this code :

```
Public Shared Function SetParent(ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndParent As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function


Private Sub ShowNewForm(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles NewToolStripMenuItem.Click, NewToolStripButton.Click, NewWindowToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim myProcess As Process = New Process()
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "D:\tesVB.exe"
    myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    myProcess.Start()
    myProcess.WaitForInputIdle()
    SetParent(myProcess.MainWindowHandle, Me.Handle)
    myProcess.WaitForExit()
End Sub
```

Above code is worked but that new child form(form1.exe) doesn't act like it should be! When i maximized or minimized it. it don't act like MDI Child Form.
Can anyone give me another better example code ? thx before.

Answer (score 3):

hahaha.... found it my self. hope this solution would be good for others.

```
Private Sub ShowNewForm(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles NewToolStripMenuItem.Click, NewToolStripButton.Click, NewWindowToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim eAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("D:\form1.exe")
    Dim eForm As Form = eAssembly.CreateInstance("form1.Form1", True)
    Me.AddOwnedForm(eForm)
    eForm.MdiParent = Me
    eForm.Show()

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice catch! I've never happened to notice those properties before. That could make for some interesting architectural decisions.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub ShowNewForm(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles NewToolStripMenuItem.Click, NewToolStripButton.Click, NewWindowToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim eAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("D:\form1.exe")
    Dim eForm As Form = eAssembly.CreateInstance("form1.Form1", True)
    Me.AddOwnedForm(eForm)
    eForm.MdiParent = Me
    eForm.Show()

End Sub
```

Runtime error

> eform is a form and eAssembly.CreateInstance("form1.Form1", True) returns an object